# Calculate probability current from density matrix

Tags: density-operator

I'm studying a one-dimensional system composed of $N$ two-level subsystems, something like a chain of spins. This system interacts with an external environment at a positive temperature and is therefore best described by a density matrix.
Now, I'd like to calculate, if it makes any sense, the probability current between (any) two of these spins as the system evolves in time from some initial conditions.
Ideally, an excitation is "injected" from one end of the chain and I'd like to observe how it travels to the other end, or dissipates, bounces back, et cetera.

The problem is, I don't know the relevant observable to this quantity.
The basic QM probability current relies on the existence of a pure state so I don't know how to use it.
I tried, then, starting by deriving an equation for the current from Noether's theorem and the phase symmetry, but I can't find how to write such a symmetry transformation for the density matrix (...if such transformation exists at all!); a pure state wavefunction gets multiplied by a phase, but what happens to the density matrix? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Are you looking for the correlation between two spins or the probability of excitation of one spin given the excitation of another? If it's the latter, the observable can be the projector onto the excited state of the final spin, while the evolution can come from the initially relaxed state subject to one spin at the end of the chain being excited at some initial time.

Comment: I'm thinking of something like an energy/heat current. Imagine that each end of the chain interacts with a thermal bath: if the two baths are set at different temperatures, one would expect a heat current flowing through the chain. That heat current is the thing I want of measure.

Comment: Ok. You can define a temperature (or excitation probability, or average energy) for each spin and look how that set of temperatures evolves with time. It's not the same as the probability current but I'm not certain that applies here